# Counting for only words in a file using a scanner Java

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get into java and i am stuck on a problem which is to count only words in a java file using a scanner

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
 sc.next(); 

 count++; }
```

and this is the answer to most of the questions i have seen although this counts everything including numbers punctuation etc.

So what is the best approach to check for words only ?

Comment: by words you mean only letters ?

Comment: i don't want to count individual letters i can do that i want to count words so a combination of characters separated by spaces and not punctuation numbers or symbols.

Comment: can you show me how more of your code?

Comment: This is much more difficult than you may realise, as it's almost impossible to distinguish between punctuation inside a word and punctuation between words.

Comment: @BoristheSpider not really ;) not with matching regex

Comment: why can't you just count number of spaces?

Comment: because 123    @!### are not words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep your original code, and them match it with (allows apostrophes but doesn't allow apostrophes at the start)

```
if (word.matches("[a-zA-Z']+") && !word.matches("'")) {

}
```

Comment: This allows apostrophes within the word so that is good however if i start by using an apostrophe it will also count, is there any way around this?

Comment: @alexyz do you not want to start with apostrophe? because `'tis` is also consider a word? but nevertheless, use the second option (i just edited it)

Comment: this seems to break my program unless there is an apostrophe at the end? i just dont want " ' " to be counted as a word on its own however it is required for cases where it is within words

Comment: @alexyz sorry.. i don't knwo what I was thinking when I posted this XD... try it now

Comment: as you say 'tis is a word and should be counted, is there anyway we can allow for lets say 'tis to be allowed and shippin' but ' on its own to be blocked? thanks for your continuous help!

Comment: @alexyz sure i guess? did you want to block all words starting with ' ?